# Campo "From" do formulário aparece como nome da conta do servidor

Tags: php, formulário

olá! Estou com um problema no meu formulário de contato.
O PHP que processa os dados e envia ao meu email, me retorna o campo "From" com o meu endereço de usuário do servidor e não como o endereço do remetente.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contact_name']) != ""){
            $to = "email@meudominio.com.br";
            $from =  $_POST["contact_email"];
            $message = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Nome: </strong>".$_POST["contact_name"]."<br />";
            $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Email: </strong>".$_POST["contact_email"]."<br />";
            $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Telefone: </strong>".$_POST["contact_phone"]."<br />";
            $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Cotacao para: </strong>".$_POST["contact_servico"]."<br />";
            $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Mensagem: </strong>".$_POST["message"]."<br />";
            $subject = 'Solicitação de cotação';        
            $headers = "De: ".$_POST["contact_email"]."\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);



    if($send)
    {
        echo "Agradecemos sua solicitação. Entraremos em contato o mais breve possível.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Erro no envio da mensagem. Por favor, verifique os campos de preenchimento.";
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['subscribe_name']) != ""){
            $to = "email@meudominio.com.br";
            $from =  $_POST["subscribe_email"];
            $message = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Nome: </strong>".$_POST["subscribe_name"]."<br />";
            $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Email: </strong>".$_POST["subscribe_email"]."<br />";
            $subject = 'Inscrição';     
            $headers = "De: ".$_POST["subscribe_email"]."\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);



    if($send)
    {
        echo "Agradecemos sua solicitação.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}


?>
```

```
<form class="contact-form" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" method="post" action="process.php" onSubmit="return false">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="Seu nome" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" class="input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="Seu E-mail" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" class="input">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="Seu telefone" name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone" class="input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="Cotacao para" name="contact_servico" id="contact_servico" class="input">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <textarea data-delay="500" class="required valid" placeholder="Mensagem" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="" type="submit" data-text="Enviar" onClick="validateContact();">Enviar</button>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada na propriedade "name" dos inputs, talvez esteja ao contrário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo **`FROM`** deve estar em inglês, no cabeçalho do seu e-mail está indo como "**`De`**" (em português).

**Altere esta linha:**

```
$headers = "De: ".$_POST["contact_email"]."\n";
```

**Para esta:**

```
$headers = "From: ".$_POST["contact_email"]."\n";
```

---

**Altere esta linha:**

```
$headers = "De: ".$_POST["subscribe_email"]."\n";
```

**Para esta:**

```
$headers = "From: ".$_POST["subscribe_email"]."\n";
```

Comment: Valeu Bruno!
Deu certinho. Era isso mesmo.

Comment: Por nada @SilvanaCampos. Depois não esqueça de marcar a resposta como solução atendida.